# .tfignore is not ignoring wildcard based files from specific directory

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I want to ignore `*.js, *.json, *.eot, *.woff` etc typescript build files from `src\main\webapp` folder only. The `*.js and *.json` files from my `src\main\java` should not get affected.

Folder structure -

```
-ProjectRoot

 - .tfignore
 - ModuleName
    - Core
       - src
         - main
           - java
           - webapp
```

Tried many dir combinations with `\` and `/` but didnt work.
For example,

```
webapp/*.js
webapp\*.js 
/*/webapp/*.js
\*\webapp\*.js
```

Comment: Did you look at the `.tfignore` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops#tfignore)?

Comment: @DanielMann yes, i checked documentation as well as all above posted questions already. My issue isnt resolved. Now I see the question is closed so i guess my issue wont be resolved.